# why local branch files were reverted?

Tags: git, github

I have a remote branch B1 which is made from master. I've committed the changes in B1 and raised a PR .

B1 was then merged into master but after some time my same commit was reverted back from master.

I pulled my the changes from master to local branch B1.

Does this cause my files(which were changed in the previous commit)in branch B1 to be reverted back ? Becasue i cannot see my changes now in my local branch B1.

i have redone the changes in my local branch B1

The files in my local branch B1 are reverted to same as that of master after i took an update from master . just after my changes were reverted

Comment: can you draw graphs of situation along time, it would make it easier to understand

Comment: What does "my same commit was reverted back from master" mean? Was the merge commit removed?

Comment: Pulling changes from master to local branch?
Merging from master to B1 will not modify your edits in B1. If you edited the same part of the code in master, you would have a conflict (and git would say so properly).

Comment: @MFnx Yes , it means the merged commit was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, your changes on your branch will be gone after merging master (your existing commits won't be changed).

Let's consider this:

```
M0-M1-M2-PR1-M3-R1
 \      /         \
  B1--B2---B3------R2
```

With `Mx` being commits on master, `Bx` commits on your branch. `PR1` is your initial, accepted pull request (bringing your branch's changes to master), `R1` is the revert of your changes (from either `B1` or `B2`) and `R2` is the merge of master to your branch (including the revert-commit `R1`).

At `PR1` the tree will contain all changes from master and your branch. When merging, Git usually looks at the *merge base* of the two branches: the point, where they last diverged so that it can compute which changes are actually required when merging.

For the first merge, this will be changes in commits `B1` and `B2`. They will get merged into the tree and then be commit as `PR1`. (**very** simplified: create a diff of the branch's changes and apply it to the other branch).

Then, `R1` (partially) reverts your changes. Git doesn't have any special notion of a revert-commit, it is simply another new commit, which has the same changset, but in reverse order (so all added lines become deleted lines and all deleted lines become added lines).

Now, when merging master back to your branch, Git will look at which commits are relevant for the merge and finds that to be `M3` and `R1`, since everything else is already included in your branch ("reachable" in Git lingo). Changes from `M3` and `R1` are applied to your branch (again, very simplified: create a diff and apply it). This also means, that the "revert-commit" will be merged into your branch (it is not contained in your branch yet) and effectively revert the changes on your branch too.

Hope that helps, if I need to clarify some details, don't hesitate to comment on this question